# Calculate maximum length of consecutive days above a certain threshold in a raster stack

Tags: r, raster

I would like to calculate the maximum length of consecutive days above a threshold `t` given a raster stack `s` as shown below:

```
library(raster)

set.seed(112)

x1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
x2=x3=x4=x5=x6=x1
x1[]= runif(ncell(x1))
x2[]= runif(ncell(x1))
x3[]= runif(ncell(x1))
x4[]= runif(ncell(x1))
x5[]= runif(ncell(x1))
x6[]= runif(ncell(x1))
s=stack(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)*56
```

Here is my current function.

```
fun <- function(x,t){
  y <- rle((x > t)*1)
  z <- y$lengths[y$values==1]
  return(max(z,0))
}
```

I have also set a parameter `q` for export as advised in the `cluster {raster}` function

```
q <- 0
```

I expect a raster layer as an output but instead the error below pops up.

```
[1] "cannot use this function"
attr(,"class")
[1] "snow-try-error" "try-error"     
Error in clusterR(s, calc, args = list(fun = fun), export = "q") : 
  cluster error
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you use random values in your example data, please also set the random seed so it's reproducible.

```
library(raster)

set.seed(42)

x1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)

s <- do.call(stack,lapply(1:6,function(x) setValues(x1,runif(ncell(x1)))*56))
```

As to your question, the only thing you need is a simple function that can be passed into `calc` to obtain the desired results:

```
cd <- function(x,t){

  y <- rle((x > t)*1)

  z <- y$lengths[y$values==1]

  return(max(z,0))

}
```

This function uses `rle`, or run length encoding, to calculate the number of consecutive runs in a vector. In this case I'm looking for the maximum number of consecutive `1`s, which come from multiplying TRUE values (value is above threshold `t`) with 1.

In the end you want to return the maximum run of a value 1, with `0` being a fallback in case there's no occurrence (sidenote: 1 indicates a single, non-consecutive occurence).

Finally, `cd` can be passed into `calc`, in this case using a threshold of 40:

```
plot(calc(s,function(x) cd(x,40)))
```

[image]

Comment: I still cannot get this going. I have edited the question for more clarity @val

Comment: @jmutua IMO my solution answers your question. I see your error is connected with using a cluster in R. That's an entirely different thing ... so probably it's best to ask a separate question