# Calculate maximum length of consecutive values above a threshold given a raster stack

Tags: r, raster

This question was initially asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255507/calculate-maximum-length-of-consecutive-days-above-a-certain-threshold-in-a-rast/56256561?noredirect=1#comment102900666_56256561). I would like to calculate the maximum length of consecutive days above a threshold `t` given a raster stack `s` as shown below:

```
library(raster)

set.seed(112)

x1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
x2=x3=x4=x5=x6=x1
x1[]= runif(ncell(x1))
x2[]= runif(ncell(x1))
x3[]= runif(ncell(x1))
x4[]= runif(ncell(x1))
x5[]= runif(ncell(x1))
x6[]= runif(ncell(x1))
s=stack(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)*56
```

Here is my current function.

```
fun <- function(x,t){
  y <- rle((x > t)*1)
  z <- y$lengths[y$values==1]
  return(max(z,0))
}
```

And my how I have used the function. I have also set a parameter `q` for export as advised in the `cluster {raster}` function

```
beginCluster()

out_ras <- clusterR(s, calc, args=list(fun=fun), export='q')

endCluster()
```

I expect a raster layer as an output but instead the a `cluster error` pops up.

```
[1] "cannot use this function"
attr(,"class")
[1] "snow-try-error" "try-error"     
Error in clusterR(s, calc, args = list(fun = fun), export = "q") : 
  cluster error
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: This is not clear. Please be specific. What is wrong with the old answer? The solution looks fine to me.

Comment: @Majid I have added some more lines of code for clarity. Ideally I would like to implement parallelization using clusterR.